# Show progress dialog on Android without blocking clicks on other UI elements

Tags: android

How do I show a progress dialog on Android without blocking clicks on the other UI elements on the screen (like Ads) ?

Comment: You can't. you should use ProgressBar view instead

Comment: By setting pDialog.setCancelable(true), its possible to click other UI elements but it will cancel the progress dialog.So no you cant do such things.

Comment: I think you can disable touch for some layouts while progress bar (not dialog) is visible until your work done..

Comment: @user2012: tapping on other elements just cancel the dialog, it doesn't have any effects on those tapped elements.

Comment: @Pinch, you are right. This means that, you have to first disappear your dialog then second time you need to touch on other view then only you will get effect.

Comment: @Pinch: yeah by default Progress dialog takes all focus when it is started, so you cant do other tasks at that point of time. I guess you have to write your own Custom class to do that.

Comment: just use a normal progress bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ProgressBar view, and create a separate overlay for the progress bar.
The most transparent way would be to create an abstract Activity and override the setContentView() method (both with id, and View, shown only with id). Than you can inherit your Activities from this one, and use it as a normal Activity with the added benefit of showProgress and hideProgress methods.

```
private HashMap<View, ProgressBar> progressBars = new HashMap<View, ProgressBar>();
private RelativeLayout overlay;

public void setContentView(int id) {
   FrameLayout combinedView = new FrameLayout();
   combinedView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
   View background = getLayoutInflater().inflate(id, null);
   background.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
   combinedView.addView(background);
   overlay = new RelativeLayout();
   overlay.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
   LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
   combinedView.addView(overlay);
   super.setContentView(combinedView);
}

public void showProgress(View view) {
   ProgressBar progressBar = progressBars.get(view);
   if (progressBar == null) {
      progressBar = new ProgressBar();
      progressBars.put(view, progressBar);
      progressBar.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
      overlay.addView(progressBar);
   }
   int[] position = view.getLocationOnScreen();
   int width = view.getWidth();
   int height = view.getHeight();
   int progressWidth = progressBar.getWidth();
   int progressHeight =progressBar.getHeight(); 
   progressBar.setMargins(position[0] + width / 2 - progressWidth/2,
   position[1] + height / 2 - progressHeight/2,0,0);
   progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void hideProgress(View view) {
   ProgressBar progressBar = progressBars.get(view);
   if (progressBar != null) {
      progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void addProgressBar(Activity activity){
    final ViewGroup rootFrameLayout = (ViewGroup) activity.getWindow().peekDecorView();
    final ViewGroup modal = new RelativeLayout(activity);
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(activity);
    LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    modal.addView(progressBar, layoutParams);
    rootFrameLayout.addView(modal, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    rootFrameLayout.invalidate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a completely `transparent` Linear or any other kind of layout with a `ProgressBar` in `center` and add this layout in a `FrameLayout` which contain all your other controls. Now when you want to show the `progress bar` make this `layout` `visible` and make `invisible` when you do not want it to show.

Answer (score 1):

[bankings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2659843/banking) [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18503290/3744681) I felt was the best and the simplest to implement. Just for the convenience of anybody wanting to use it, rather make the method return ProgressBar and when you want to remove this progress bar, you can use this return value to just set its visibility to gone as shown for example

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Hope it adds value to the above answers.

Answer (score 0):

When a dialog appears, it adds a layer to underlaying view blocking all events on it.
To achieve what you are looking for, you can create a view similar to dialog view and show it instead of dialog. For dialogs and transparent background activity, your target won't be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

@banking's [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18503290/3744681) is sweet and short, I have modified it a little to use with layout file instead of creating it with Java code:

**progress_spinner.xml:** (in layout folder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java**:

```
ProgressBar progressBar=null;


public void addProgressBar(Activity activity) {
    ViewGroup rootFrameLayout = (ViewGroup) activity.getWindow().peekDecorView();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View progressModal = inflater.inflate(R.layout.progress_spinner, rootFrameLayout, false);
    rootFrameLayout.addView(progressModal, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    rootFrameLayout.invalidate();
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) progressModal.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
}

public void hideProgressBar() {
    if (progressBar != null)
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

public void showProgressBar() {
    if (progressBar != null)
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```